# Show that $G^k=G^{\gcd(n,k)}$ if $G$ is a finite Abelian group with $|G|=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Here's the question I am working on from the book Contemporary Abstract Algebra (10th Edition), Joseph A. Gallian. (Q48 from Chapter 4).

> For a positive integer $k$ and an Abelian group $G$, prove that $G^k:=\{x^k\mid x\in G\}$
> is a subgroup of $G$.
> If $G$ is Abelian and $|G|=40$, prove that $G^3=G$, $G^{15}=G^5$, and $G^{28}=G^4$.
> Generalize to the case that $|G|=n$ and $k$ is any positive integer.

At the first sight, I obtained (without proof in mind) the conclusion $G^k=G^{\gcd(n,k)}$, so I tried to prove this statement.

> I first try to prove $G^k\subseteq G^{\gcd(n,k)}$.
> For any $x^k \in G^k$, we have $x^k=(x^{\gcd(n,k)})^{n/\gcd(n,k)}\in G^{\gcd(n,k)}$, so the subset relation follows.

Then I tried to prove $G^{\gcd(n,k)}\subseteq G^k$.

> By Bezout's Identity, there exists some integers $s,t$ such that $sk+tn=\gcd(n,k)$.
> Then $x^{\gcd(n,k)}=x^{sk+tn}=(x^k)^s(x^n)^t$.

From which I am quite sure the result follows immediately from Lagrange's Theorem. But up to this point, Lagrange's Theorem has not been introduced yet in the book.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated!!

P.S. I have seen an argument which proves that every element $g\in G$ obeys $g^n=e$ for Abelian G. Not sure if it helps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By Bezout's Identity, there exists some integers $s,t$ such that $sk+tn=\gcd(n,k)$.
> Then $x^{\gcd(n,k)}=x^{sk+tn}=(x^k)^s(x^n)^t$.

Since $n=|G|, $ we have $x^n=e$, for $\forall x\in G$. So we get

$$x^{\gcd(n,k)}=x^{sk+tn}=(x^k)^s(x^n)^t=(x^k)^s$$

> For a positive integer $k$ and an Abelian group $G$, prove that $G^k:=\{x^k|x\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Since $G^k$ is a subgroup, and $x^k\in G^k$, by the closure axiom of a (sub)group, we have $(x^k)^s\in G^k$, hence

$$G^{\gcd(n,k)}\subseteq G^k$$

Comment: Is there any other way of approaching the question? I prefer not using the fact that $g^n=e \  \forall g \in G$ since it is related to cosets, something which has not yet been mentioned in the book.

Comment: You have to use this property.